# Sacar año de una fecha con el módulo datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime

estoy tratando de implementar una función, en la cual recibe una lista de tuplas, y un entero con un año y devuelve el día más frio de ese año y la temperatura mínima alcanzada.

He intentado hacerlo de 2 maneras distintas, son estas

```
def obtener_dia_mas_frio_año(registroclima, parametro_anyo):
    for fecha, _,  _, temp_min in registroclima:
        if fecha.datetime(datetime.year) == parametro_anyo:
            tupla = (fecha.datetime(datetime.day), min(temp_min))
            lista = [tupla]
    return lista


def obtener_dia_mas_frio_año(registroclima, parametro_anyo):
    for fecha, _,  _, temp_min in registroclima:
        if fecha.datetime.year() == parametro_anyo:
            tupla = (fecha.datetime.day, min(temp_min))
            lista = [tupla]
    return lista
```

En ambos casos recibo este error:

> AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'datetime'

fecha es de tipo datetime, y temp_min es de tipo float.

También he pensado en hacerlo como un diccionario, aunque no estoy seguro.

Gracias!!

Comment: ¿Removiste `datetime` de `fecha.datetime`?

Comment: Para acceder al año, alcanza con acceder al atributo year: fecha.year (no es necesario llamar nada ni acceder al atributo datetime (el cual no existe))